# Restrict a find query MongoDB with ruby driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a mongo query that look like this :

```
coll.find({ foo: bar }, {sort: { '$natural' => -1 }, limit: 1})
```

My problem is that my collection contain a huge quantity of documents and the find is really slow.
So I was wondering if I could restrict the query for the last x inserted documents ?
Something like this :

```
coll.find({ foo: bar }, {sort: { '$natural' => -1 }, limit: 1, max_doc: 10_000})
```

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: Have you investigated why the find is slow? Do you have an index? Do you need the natural order sort? An index on `{ "foo" : 1 }` will fulfill the query if you drop the natural order sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that restriction at query time. But you could have a separated caped collection for this effect.

You insert on both and do this query on the caped collection which will will only retain the last N documents.

But this will only fit if you don't need to update or remove documents from that collection.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections